# while i am giving enter key, it is not working..msg is not appending to anywhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**JavaScript**

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);

function MyController($scope,$firebase){

var ref= new Firebase('https://alpha-db.firebaseio.com/');
$scope.messages= $firebase(ref);
$scope.addMessage=function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode !=13) return;
      $scope.messages.$add({from: $scope.name,body: $scope.msg});//funtion not working....
      $scope.msg ="";
 }
}
```

errors occured are `://error:angularfire.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined..`

`angular.min.js:84 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24firebaseProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebase
    at Error (native)`

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src='lib/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/angularfire.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/firebase.js'></script>
<script src='js/app.js'></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase.js">        </script>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/main.css'>
</head>
<body ng-controller='MyController'>
<h1>CHAT APP </h1>
<div class="list-messages" id="listMessages">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat='msg in messages'><em>{{msg.from}}</em>:{{msg.body}}   </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="new-message" id="newMessage">
<input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="name..">
<input type="text" ng-model="msg" ng-keydown="addMessage($event)"   placeholder="Message..">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misplaced the order of references, you should load **`firebase.js`** before loading **`angularfire.min.js`**. Change the order as

```
<script src='lib/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/firebase.js'></script>
<script src='lib/angularfire.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/app.js'></script>
```